# Pin OneNote Section to Start

Tags: pin-to-start, onenote

I have a OneNote "tab" pinned to my Start screen.  I've had this for quite a while, at lease since I've had my Lumia 925 (nearly a year).

I want to pin another note to the start screen, but I only see the option to pin a shortcut to "New Note" from OneNote. I've tried long pressing the note I want to pin, but it isn't an option.

Does anyone know if this is possible, or was the functionality removed at some point?

I'm currently running 8.1 Dev Preview.

Comment: Strange, I can pin multiple pages to my Start screen just fine. Are you sure you're not trying to pin an entire section or notebook?

Comment: I was thinking I could pin a section since I wanted to pin "Quick Notes" that Cortana creates.  Got lost in the OneNote hierarchy!

Comment: Yeah, you can't pin notebooks or sections, just pages. At least in WP8. I understand this was possible in WP7, so perhaps MS will bring back this ability in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open the page, and there is shortcut to *pin to start* for each page under the *three-dot menu* (applies for both Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1). Please check once more.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to pin the "section" because I wanted to pin the notes created by Cortana.  I see, yes, it does work for pages like it always has.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an app that allows you to pin OneNote notebooks and sections to the WP start screen (needs 8.1). It's called [Pinmore for OneNote](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=5ac3fd50-4760-4354-8447-c2adb322c80f).  I hope you find it useful.